# How to reuse the cache between several lookups

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS2008 package that incrementally loads a table Clients with 10M records and a table ClientRelations with 6M records. A clientrelation is a relation between 2 clients.

In the RelatedClientsETL dataflow I get my relations from a flat file source, and I do 2 lookups on the same Clients table.

Would it be good to use the Cache Connection Manager here, or should I use the Partial Cache lookup option on both lookups? Or do you advise another option?

Memory of the Production SQL Server that executes this package = 8GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it is preferred to use `Full Cache mode` in lookup as this will reduce the `database load` ,thereby reducing the number of `hits` on the database .Since you have sufficient memory to hold the data ,i suggest you should use Full Cache .SSIS uses a `buffer-oriented architecture` to efficiently load and manipulate datasets in `memory` therefore the lookup tends to be faster in this mode .

`Partial cache mode` is generally avoided and also [not a better choice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/10/18/lookup-cache-modes.aspx).It is useful only in cases where you have less number of rows to be processed .It caches data only when there is a match found .There is no pre-execute caching done as in the case of `Full Cache` so loading time is fast but number of hits to the database is more .

`CCM` (`Cache Connection Manager`) is used when you want to re-use the cache to reduce `database load` but then again you need to test it your self by using `OleDB connection vs CCM`  in lookup .

There is a free tool [bidshelper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) which will help you monitor the performance of individual tasks else try to isolate your destination and other components except lookpup and source .
Replace destination with RowCount transformation and measure the performance by checking in execution results  tab for (time ,number of rows) .Perform it for both `Full Cache` and `CCM`

There is a [whitepaper](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc966529) which superbly explains on overall SSIS performance

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the RowCount. I already had Bidshelper but didn't use the Performance monitor before. Also +1 for the whitepaper!